# Customize the view on Manage apex classes page

Tags: apex, configuration

This is a configuration item. On the manage apex classes page, where we see all the apex classes, I am trying to create a view where i can see apex classes developed by some developers only. There is a last modified by field where it shows developer name and date and time stamp. How do we create a filter condition where we can last modified by equal say chris and joe. I used the contains filter but it does not show more than 2 developers. I want to create a view to see classes modified by 5 developers and i need to know the filter condition?
Thanks
Buyan

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track to reach your goal.  You'd need to create a filter, use the Contains operator and you can either separate your strings by comma in one filter (effectively each comma is an 'OR') or you can add up to 10 filters and apply filter logic to separate your filters by OR instead of AND (which is the default filter logic).

Filter logic is explained in detail here:
https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=reports_filter.htm&siteLang=en_US